# how to create a SKbitmap from a local image xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bitmap, skiasharp

I'm trying to create a tiled image in Xamarin following this example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/shaders/bitmap-tiling)

but I ran into an error. Here the assembly stream is always null.

```
            SKBitmap origBitmap;

            Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
            {
                origBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
            }
```

I also made sure that the image build type is set to **Embedded Resource**

any idea how to solve this? or is there a better way to load a local image as a SKbitmap

Thanks in advance

Comment: double check that your `resourceID` is correct, check the properties of that embedded resource to find the correct name.

Comment: Found the dumb error.... a nesting problem. thx for the help

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for SuchiHangover (Great name) in the comments

I rechecked and found the problem

the image resource should be as followed "YOURASSEMLBY.IMAGENAME.IMAGETPYE(PNG,JPG,...)"

if the image is saved in a folder add its name before the image name but avoid nesting

meaning no folder inside another

and make sure the image build type is set to **Embedded Resource**